# get contents of data array from fwrite parameter - to print out data with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

I have some code that reads this:

```
int SaveTemplateToFile(char* Name, FTR_DATA Template )
{
    //NSLog(@"trying to save template to file");

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( Name, "w+b");
    if( fp == NULL ) return FALSE;

    int Result = fwrite( Template.pData, 1, Template.dwSize, fp ) == Template.dwSize ? TRUE : FALSE;
    fclose(fp);

    return Result;
}
```

I understand that this will write out the data retrieved from `Template.pData` into a file named whatever is stored in the `Name` variable.
This is what the `.tmpl`'s contents reads:

[image: contents of template file]

### Task/Question:

I am simply trying to store this data into a variable so that I can send this data to my webserver database and store it in a blob file for retrieval at a later time. This will also allow me to get rid of the `fwrite` function which I wont need since im storing everything onto the sebserver instead of storing it locally.

I am currently finding trouble reading this data. I am getting a crash when trying to output this data array, I also present what the datatype structure looks like:

[image]

Where `DGTVOID` is of `typedef void DGTVOID`.

How can I correctly read the contents of template? I was thinking if I understood what datatype it is, then I would be able to retrieve the data correcty.

### Update 1

Thanks to Paulw11 I am able access a very small portion of the data using `%s` instead of `%@` which originally lead to a crash. Here is what is being printed now, a few funky upside down question marks:

[image]

Is there a way to output the contents of this datastream from `Template.pData` without having to save the data onto the direction first as a file?

Comment: Is this C++ or Objective C?  What is the setting in your compiler or IDE?

Comment: I am programming in `objective-c`, I believe I have `c` code in the same file, not `c++`. sorry

Comment: I get an `exc_bad_access` when trying to access the `Template.pData` variable. fwrite can accept this variable happily, but when I try storing this data into a variable or simply trying to output into the contents, it throws the error. Please do have a look at my screenshot in the post.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the compiler is set to `Default compiler (Apple LLVM 5.1)`

Comment: Have you tried "%s" instead of "%@" in your format string?  Template.pdata is more like a CString than an NSString. If pData is arbitrary binary data then %s also won't work properly because it will stop printing as soon as it hits a 0 byte (or if you buffer doesn't contain a 0 it will run off the end and give you an exception). The proper way to dump the buffer is to iterate over its length and print each byte.

Comment: @Paulw11, hey Paul, thank you for taking a look. Yes, the likely chance is that there will be a 0 digit in the .tmpl file. I wanted to avoid saving this data to a file, since I don't require this file to be stored locally, but for it to be stored remotely instead. Is there a way to store this data into a variable (so that I can send the data to a webserver)? The challenge is in printing this datatype, (I feel that if I can print this into the debugger, then I can easily send the data off to my webserver). Although when I try to access it, the  program crashes.

Comment: Wahaay, @Paulw11, so I tried using `%s` instead of `%@` for the reason you explained but its printing a few upside down question marks and then thats it, I'm not able to paste that output onto here. I will update the post with a screenshot. I believe its as you said, it stopped outputting as soon as it hit a 0.

Comment: This is because your buffer isn't a string.  See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing you should do is convert your buffer to an NSData instance -

```
NSData template = [NSData dataWithBytes:Template.pData length:Template.dwSize];
```

Once you have that then you can Base64 encode the data for transmission over a web request -

```
NSString *templateStr = [template base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

If you are targeting a version earlier than iOS7 then you can use the deprecated method

```
NSString *templateStr = [template base64Encoding];
```

Comment: Can I ask how you knew to go for `base64encoding` instead of doing something like `NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:template encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`?

Comment: Because you are dealing with binary data, not a character string, therefore character encodings are irrelevant.  HTTP cannot transfer binary data directly, so Base64 encoding is used to translate 8 bit binary data into packed printable data in a reasonably efficient manner (average overhead is 37%).  Think of it this way, in C, strings are represented by arrays of bytes (with a 0 terminator), but not all arrays of bytes represent (or can be treated as) a string.

Comment: @Gotcha Paulw11. Thanks for your concise answer. Last mini-question, to convert the string back to NSData again as I will be sending strings instead of JSON objects to my server, whats the correct way to convert it back again? I could find a `64` alternative to the `NSData *dataFromString = [templateStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` approach.

Comment: You can use the `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:` method in NSData